# Does automatically hoisting slow down the performance of JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hoisting

Lately, I was studying Scope in Javascript. I want to know whether automatically hoisting is done at compile time or at the time of executing the code(run time). If it does at run time then I have another question does auto-hoisting will slow down the performance of the Javascript program.

```
something = a(); 
function a(){
 console.log("hoisting");
 return 10;
}
var something;
```

Should we use manual hoisting or it would be better to use automatically hoisting?

Comment: The specification is pretty clear about what happens when a function is evaluated. The hoisting happens when the new execution context for the function is created. I.e. it will happen every time the function is called and it doesn't matter where you place the `var` statement. Per spec, the engine has to parse the function for all `var` statements anyway. Having said that, I'm sure real implementations probably only do that once and keep a "canonical" representation of the function around, instead of the original one (and who knows what happens with JIT compilation anyway).

Comment: What do you mean with *"manual hoisting"*?

Comment: People keep talking about "compile time" but what exactly do they mean by that in the context of JavaScript?

Comment: parsing I guess then converting to AST

Comment: According to the spec, https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation happens on every function call, not at parse time. But as I already said, there are definitely optimizations an implementation could do, though that's not my area of expertise. It certainly seems to be reasonable to collect information about all variable declarations inside the function *once*.

Comment: Also re hoisting: People have a different understanding of what exactly it's supposed to mean. Fact is that, according to the spec, when a function is called a new execution context is created, which holds a new environment. Then the function body is processed to find all variable declarations (`var`, `let`, `const` (and function declarations)) and bindings for those names are created in the new environment. `var` declarations are initialized with `undefined`. Then the body is actually evaluated.

Comment: *May I know why does it matter to you?* Even if there is an ever slight slowdown, it is so negligible that it wouldn't matter what-so-ever for 100% of all programs written in javascript, since if performance matter that match, the program wouldn't be written in javascript in the first place. Since JS meant for web, and not landing rockets on asteroids

Comment: @vsync just want to have proper knowledge I would say. please don't judge me on this.

Comment: @SubratoPatnaik - I like your question as you seems a curious person, just want to say that the result of this inquiry would not affect the *perceived* performance of any program.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To put my comments as an answer:

People have a different understanding of what hoisting supposed to mean. Fact is that, according to the spec, *every time* a function is called a new execution context is created, which holds a new environment. Then [the function body is processed](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-functiondeclarationinstantiation) to find all variable declarations (`var`, `let`, `const` (and function declarations)) and bindings for those names are created in the new environment. `var` declarations are initialized with `undefined`. Then the body is actually evaluated.

Considering this, from the perspective of the engine it doesn't really matter where you place the `var` declaration, the whole body has to be processed anyway.

Having said that, I would be surprised if actual implementations didn't cache that information. After all, the variable declarations in a function don't change between function calls.

Comment: line 1 in my example is a function expression. How javascript parse that line?

Comment: Sorry, line1 is not a function expression. But, wanted to know how function expression is parsed? Also, I know this question not much relate to hoisting.   Any small suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: You mean because the name of the algorithm is "FunctionDeclarationInstantiation"? Despite that name, the exact same algorithm is used to the evaluate the body of function expressions.

Answer (score 5):

As I know, There are no performance issues. The initializations are getting done in compile time. So doesn't matter you initialize on top or bottom, The JS engine will create the references in compile time.

**BUT**

If you forgot to initialize at the bottom, It will be initialized as `undefined` by default. Because of hoisting it’s considered a practice to declare `functions` or `variables` at the top of their respective scopes.

[JavaScript: What is Hoisting? (Recommended)](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-is-hoisting-dfa84512dd28)

Comment: Could you also help me to know how function expression is parsed? I know that the function declaration and variable declaration does at the compiling process.

Answer (score 2):

It is not done at run time.
It's in the compile process.
So it doesn't slow down the performance.
Just before the code is executed the compiler scans for all variable and function declarations and allocates them in the memory.

Comment: javascript is not a language that goes a compilation process

Comment: @vsync theoretically, yes.  but the engines does that for performance optimization behind the scenes. 
"V8 increases performance by **compiling JavaScript to native machine code** before executing it, versus executing bytecode or interpreting it."

Comment: @Tibebes.M - Ho, **that** compilation process. I thought he meant in the "traditional" sense. 10x